# Difference between two intervals

Tags: calculus

What is the difference between the real intervals $]0,\infty[$ and $[R,\infty[$ with $R>0$ using a small enough $R$?

It seems to me like using a small enough $R$ would mean any real number greater than $0$ is included in the second interval, but when determining the domain of uniform convergence of sequences of functions such as

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{-kx}$$

which converges uniformly over $[R,\infty[$ but not over $]0,\infty[$, we see that these intervals are not equal.

Comment: "*using a small enough $R$*"..."*a small enough $R$ would mean any real number greater than $0$ is included in the second interval*"...  You should be made aware that in standard real-analysis the only [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) is zero.  In the second interval $\frac{1}{2}R$ is not included for any $R>0$, regardless how small $R$ is, despite $\frac{1}{2}R$ being a positive real number.  In fact, no number in the interval $(0,R)$ is included in the second interval, while each of those are included in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval  $ (0, \infty)$ contains R/2 for any fixed R>0 that you have chosen whereas the interval $ (R, \infty)$ does not contain R/2

Answer (score 1):

Well what you probably intend to say is that $(0,\infty)=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[1/n,\infty)$ which is correct. But when you choose a fixed value $R>0$ then the interval $[R,\infty)$ does not contain any number between $0$ and $R$. And $(0,\infty)$ does contain all those numbers. Do not try to think of $R$ as a sequence of positive numbers getting smaller and smaller. It is just one positive number and there are many positive numbers smaller than it.